# Rails STI routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, sti

I've got an article model which uses STI.  The sub classes are emotions, categories, gateways etc...

In my routes I've got

```
resources :emotions, :controller => 'articles'
resources :categories, :controller => 'articles'
resources :gateways, :controller => 'articles'
```

This makes all the different sub classes available at /articles/108 or emotions/108 or categories/108 - it doesn't matter which subclass you stick at the front they all work for all articles.

I would like all my url helpers to produce links to articles/id - at the moment they still go to the particular sub class.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If article is the base class of another derived class like gateway (`class Gateway < Article`), then maybe just use the urls generated by `resources :articles`. It should be possible to use the articles helper `article_path(gateway)` since the subclasses are derived from the base class.