# Rails and Conditional STI Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I have a STI system something like this:

**Model:** `Fruit`

**Various Types** (via a `type` column): `Apple`, `Orange`, `Banana`, `Grape`

So currently I would have routes like this:

```
url_for(Apple.first) = /apples/1
url_for(Orange.first) = /oranges/2
url_for(Banana.first) = /bananas/3
etc...
```

After implementing this I have a situation where I would want a select set of Fruit types to default back to just plain `Fruit` i.e. no STI BUT still keep the type.  For example lets say I wanted Apples and Oranges to just be plain old fruit:

```
url_for(Apple.first) = /fruit/1
url_for(Orange.first) = /fruit/2
url_for(Banana.first) = /bananas/3
```

I know that I can do this:

```
fruit_path(Apple.first) = /fruit/1
fruit_path(Orange.first) = /fruit/2
```

The issue I have with the workaround above is that I have a pile of logic, helpers, etc. that now breaks if I do this.

I know I can clear the `type` column but that means I lose that type data.  I guess I could set a second column (`fruit_type` etc.) to save this.  Seems less ideal but may be my best option.

For reference this question / answer is close to what I am looking for:

[Rails STI routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586601/rails-sti-routing)

The question I am asking: is there a way (in the STI models perhaps) to 'disable' STI on a per-type basis while retaining the `type` field?

Comment: Its not really about STI - [ActiveModel::Naming#route_key](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-c-param_key) governs how a model are turned into a param key. This is just based of the class name and if you want a `Banana` to behave like a Fruit you can implement `def self.model_name; ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, parent.class); end` that replaces the route keys and everying. I'm not sure if there is a way to override just a single method but since its Ruby you could just provide another object that quacks like a  ActiveModel::Name.

Comment: My question may have not been well worded yet I think you may have suggested what I may be looking for.  I am going to have a look at this approach.

Comment: https://www.mendelowski.com/docs/ruby/overriding-model-name-in-rails/

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fruit
  # just for the sake of the example
  include ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.uses_parent_name
    define_singleton_method :model_name do
      ActiveModel::Name.new(self.name, nil, Fruit.name)
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Apple < Fruit
  uses_parent_name
end
```

```
class Orange < Fruit
  uses_parent_name
end
```

```
class Banana < Fruit
end
```

`uses_parent_name` is just a simple "macro-method" that defines a `model_name` class method. [`.model_name`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-i-model_name) is how ActiveModel translates model instances into routes, i18n keys and parameter keys.

```
irb(main):024:0> Apple.model_name.route_key
=> "fruits"
irb(main):026:0> Orange.model_name.route_key
=> "fruits"
irb(main):025:0> Banana.model_name.route_key
=> "bananas"
```